# Wait for Outlook to load through the command prompt

Tags: cmd, outlook

I'm trying to trigger a python script via the command prompt. One of the requirements is opening Outlook before the script starts. Is there a way for the command prompt to wait until the application loads and then trigger the script?

My trigger in the command prompt is:

```
start outlook.exe
```

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on that. I did not know. I'm not from this field. :D

Comment: There are three options;  1 - Use `timeout` in your cmd script to wait for a set amount of time (say 1 minute) so you can be sure outlook probably loaded.  2 -  Use PowerShell to start outlook and check for its's state, this also allows you to select a profile and provide a password through the script if required.  3 - Change your python script to start outlook ans check it's state.  By itself cmd is not be able to check the state of outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, automate Outlook from your Python script, not just launch a new process. First, you should import `win32com.client`, for that you need to install pywin32:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Then you can create a new Outlook Application instance:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
```

So, you just need to subscribe to the [Application.Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.startup) event which is fired when Microsoft Outlook is starting, but after all add-in programs have been loaded.

Comment: I cannot do this as there are multiple versions of MS Office installed on my computer, and I cannot change my registry directly because of access issues. That was one reason why I wanted to control it via the cmd prompt by launching the exe from the specific path.

Comment: You cannot have multiple versions of Office installed. Installing a new version will either overwrite the previous version or prompt you to uninstall it first.

Comment: So I have office 365 (which is not activated) and office 2013 which is up and running. I don't understand how that works. My system came with these softwares to me.